# Which function should be use to converting string to long double?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, long-double

Note that in general, `double` is different from `long double`.

`strtod` converts string to `double`, but which function should be use to converting string to long double?

Comment: In C++, the preferred method would be [stold](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/stof), if it's available.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C++03, use `boost::lexical_cast`, or:

```
std::stringstream ss(the_string);
long double ld;
if (ss >> ld) {
    // it worked
}
```

In C99, use `strtold`.

In C89, use `sscanf` with `%Lg`.

In C++11 use `stold`.

There may be subtle differences as to exactly which formats each one accepts, so check the details first...

Comment: This led me to the correct way to convert a string to a 64-bit (long double) on a microchip PIC32.  _dstrtod() in stdlib.h   Who knew??  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You've tagged your question as "C++", so I'm going to give you a C++ answer:

Why not just use streams?

```
std::stringstream ss(myString);
long double x;
ss >> x;
```

Answer (score 1):

In c++, I can only recommend `boost::lexical_cast` (or in general via the IOStreams).

In c ? no idea.

Comment: Just a hint on C for you Matthieu, all conversions like that, you could do with *printf/*scanf

Answer (score 1):

You can use `istream` to read long double from string. See here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

If you like `scanf` family of functions, read with `%Lf`